# Why is this output of the preprocessor seemingly not making sense?

Tags: c, clang

Sorry for the bad title, hopefully my explanation is clearer.

I have the following `c` program:

`clang_test.c`

```
#include "clang_test2.c"
int main()
{
    somefunc();
    return 0;
}
```

`clang_test2.c`

```
int somefunc()
{
    return 5;
}
```

I then compile it using clang with the `-E` parameter in order to see the result of the preprocessor.

```
clang.exe -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -E .\clang_test.c
```

The preprocessor output is this:

```
# 1 ".\\clang_test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 324 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 ".\\clang_test.c" 2

# 1 "./clang_test2.c" 1
int somefunc()
{
 return 5;
}
# 3 ".\\clang_test.c" 2

int main()
{
 somefunc();
 return 0;
}
```

This works as expected and I get no compilation error if I try to compile it regularly without `-E`.

For the sake of experimentation I modified `clang_test.c` to not `#include clang_test2.c`:

```
int main()
{
     somefunc();
     return 0;
}
```

I then tried to compile using:

```
clang.exe -std=c99 -pedantic-errors .\clang_test2.c .\clang_test.c
```

And I get a compiler error saying:

```
.\clang_test.c:13:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'somefunc' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
somefunc();
```

But if I look at the output of the preprocessor, it seems like it should work because `somefunc()` is still declared above the `main` function where it's used:

```
# 1 ".\\clang_test2.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 324 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 ".\\clang_test2.c" 2
int somefunc()
{
 return 5;
}
# 1 ".\\clang_test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 324 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 ".\\clang_test.c" 2

int main()
{
 somefunc();
 return 0;
}
```

So based on this observation, is it not reliable to look at the output of the preprocessor in order to diagnose problems related to function definitions/declarations? 
And also since the only difference between the 2 preprocessor outputs is this block of text:

```
# 1 ".\\clang_test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 324 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 ".\\clang_test.c" 2
```

What could it be doing to prevent `somefunc()` from being properly forward declared?

Comment: The preprocessor output you show after removing the `#include` and recompiling is old preprocessor output. I suspect you did not execute another `clang` with `-E`. Executing `clang` without `-E` will not change the file containing the preprocessor output that was produced earlier. If you execute a new `clang` with `-E`, you will see the preprocessor output has changed.

Comment: I didnt mention it in the post because I thought it was obvious, but I did re-run clang.exe with -E. You can try it yourself.

Comment: I did try it, and that is not the output I get. You have made some mistake with file names or saving files from buffers to disk or errors in typing commands or something else. Put the commands in a script so they are completely reproducible and try again.

Comment: What output do you get from the preprocessor after removing the `#include "clang_test2.c"`? I checked again and I get the same 2 outputs I put in my original question. There's still those same 7 lines that start with `#` inserted between `somefunc` and `main`.

Comment: Start fresh in a new directory with new files with new names. The output you report is not possible in a reasonable way when the source file `clang_test.c` does not contain `#include "clang_test2.c"`. We can see that because the line in the preprocessor output that says `# 1 ".\\clang_test2.c" 2` is telling us that GCC is reading the following lines from `clang_test2.c`. If you passed only `clang_test.c` to GCC, and it did not include `clang_test2c.`, GCC would have no way of knowing that file name. So we **know** the source file being compiled at the time did contain that `#include`.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
clang.exe -std=c99 -pedantic-errors .\clang_test2.c .\clang_test.c
```

does not just concatenate the two files and compile them. It compiles each of the C files separately to object (`.o`) files and then links them. You get the error because compiled alone,

```
int main()
{
    somefunc();
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't define `somefunc`.  You'll need a prototype to tell the compiler its type:

```
int somefunc(void);

int main(void)
{
    somefunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should be using proper prototypes throughout. Functions with no arguments should be be declared with `void` argument lists. Old style function interfaces (e.g. with arg lists `()`) allow many kinds of errors that prototypes allow the compiler to detect.

On the other hand the output of the compiler with -E

```
clang.exe -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -E .\clang_test2.c .\clang_test.c
```

*does* concatenate the two files and send them through the C preprocessor. The difference - compiling to object and liking vice concatenating - explains the behaviors you see.

Comment: This answer does not address the question that was asked. The question is not about why the compilation fails or prototypes or declarations. The question is about why the preprocessor output with `-E` apparently does not match the compiler behavior without `-E`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right I didn't explicitly say that -E with multiple inputs concatenates them. The OP had obviously figured that out for him or herself. I've now added it in summary.